# How to force third party service respect the security?

Tags: c#, web-services, security, ssl, encryption

I have to come up with an integration process to allow existing system to use external data providers. The system is a medical timetable web site, using ASP.NET MVC, that allows the patients to schedule their appointments to doctors.

As far as I go you can see on a figure below:

[image: Basic schema of expected integration]

All the providers must expose my contract `ISuperIntegration` which will be develop by me. I won't be developing `External service 1` and `External service 2`, they will be developed by other companies.

Here the issue comes: basing on the concept of that I could require the way providers should setup their services to communicate with my website properly, I want to forbid for another third party clients consume `"External Service 1"` and `"External Service 2"`, Or at least make it difficult to do that.

Here is a list of stuff I am setting:

1. `ISuperIntegration` interface. It contains operations related to my domain such as `GetSchedule`, `GetDoctors` and so on.
2. Transport protocol. I don't want it to be complicated so I'm thinking about using `HTTP`.
3. And could define some general recommendations but they could be easily avoided.

At the moment I'm thinking of using HTTPS with certificate authentication. It would require the implementer to setup their infrastructure so my web site could properly consume the data.

If I would go with basic `HTTP`, the implementer would just leave their service to be easily consumed by anyone else, which I don't want.

I hope my question is clear. Will be happy to give any other explanations you want.

I'll really appreciate any your responses, commits. Thank you!

Comment: It is not clear. Does your system (ASP.NET app) consume External services?

Comment: @MaxKvt Sorry about that. Yes, it is going to consume by adding an external service reference to it.

Comment: So, you have web service (or API) for external clients, and you thinking  abount security?

Comment: @MaxKvt Actually, I don't have nor a service nor an API at the moment but yes, I'm thinking about security because I was told to thought about that.

Answer (score 7):

I'd always use HTTPS for things like this. Let's just say that's the cost of doing business. You simply cannot have anyone with a sniffer grab that kind of traffic out of the sky. There's a reason why all banking etc. use HTTPS for things that should be secure.

Apart from that, web services have pretty standard mechanisms for security, I'd recommend looking at OAuth over HTTPS. There are plenty of implementations for that.

If your talking about basic web sites, I'd use a standard security mechanism as well like group based security (which boils down to a username + password). Again, there are plenty of implementations for that.

Basically my main word of advice is: don't go inventing stuff when it comes to security. If you're not an expert, you're probably going to get it wrong, and end up with something that can be intercepted by a third party or (much) worse.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1. Basic authentication over HTTP.
   PRO. Easy to implemet
   CON. UserCredentials was going in clear text throuh the network
2. Implement WS-Security with WCF. For example, they can sign their requests.
   PRO. Easy to implement with WCF
   CON. Java clients can faced with problems
3. You can force clients to use HTTPS.
   CON. You should setup your web server.

Comment: Thank you for your response. First option is not enough to accomplish that I am going to do because the implementer can just pass it by and not to check login or password. Second is vendor specific, I'm not sure all the systems will be Microsoft based. Third option is the best so far, it seems to be good for this. Could you please give me more your thoughts about it?

Comment: We had setup proxy server between our inner network and the internet. That proxy ask user for a certificate and then authenticate it in the inner network domain. Clients who use our web services just pass certificate other the transport.
Another possible situation is to set up application server, in instance, IIS with server security sertificate. That allow you to use SSL/HTTPS

Comment: I can't control how `External service 1` and `External service 2` would be developed. I just supply reglament how my own client (my web app) would use their services. If client (my web app) would use SSL encryption different for each external service, would it require services to setup communication the way no alien wouldn't use their services?

Comment: You should discuss this question with the service developers! You say that you cant affect this services.

Comment: Yeah, I can't. But I can define the way they should expose their services (like I can say my client would use their services only through HTTPS with certificate authentication).

Comment: Ok. External service 1, External service 2, where they will be hosted? Is there only two services or it can be more?

Comment: They can be located anywhere over the Internet. There are could be more than 2 services, I took only two services just for example.

Comment: I think they (service developers) should implement HTTPS option and basic authentication for the services.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100628/discussion-between-max-kvt-and-kseen).

Comment: I think basic authentication is redundant so we can just use certificate authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You are like Oracle, they want people to develop in Java language but they also want to forbid competitors to run the Java compiled code on non Oracle's virtual machines, or at least make it difficult to do that :)

So you can do the same by protecting your interface with patent or copyright law. However, I doubt that it is patentable or copyrightable :)

Answer (score 0):

Considering the privacy sensitivity of the data, IMHO it must be encrypted while in transport. Hence HTTPS not HTTP.

Authentication of your service to those providing services to you: well essentially it's up to them, not up to you who they expose it to, similarly how they want it protected is their call. Now assuming you do have a way to make them do the right thing...

Client certificates aren't that expensive nor prohibitive in setup to get up and running. But you do need to register the client certificate (every time it is renewed!) with the server in order to get the needed authorisation (just recognizing it's a valid cert isn't enough: anybody can apply for a (validly signed) certificate ...) .

But all that is relatively painless and rather well documented around the web, and it can be done on almost any platform of choice.

Answer (score 0):

As several people mentioned these earlier you can't guarantee that those external companies will expose your service with specific security settings, it's up to them.

If you are responsible for developing MVC application and WCF service you can only force someone to use specific security settings on the layer between your WCF services and those External 1 and 2 providers. 
Btw, [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/wcf/wcf_security.htm) is a good tutorial that can be useful if you want to improve your knowledge about how to configure WCF security.

How External Services  expose your service it's up to them. Just image that this is normal web 'proxy' behavior.

Maybe the architecture which your company adopted it is not the best for this solution